# How to work around sp_blitzwho lock timeout?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, sp-blitz

Running `sp_blitzwho @GetLiveQueryPlan = 1` on SQL2019 to monitor a big index rebuild operation but running into the following error:

> Lock request time out period exceeded.

Anything I can do to avoid this error?

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you're on the latest version of sp_BlitzWho. This issue was reported and fixed over a year ago in [this Github issue](https://github.com/BrentOzarULTD/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit/issues/2907).

If you're on the latest version, and you're still experiencing the error, that means SQL Server isn't honoring isolation level requests in the DMVs. This wouldn't be the first time we've run into this issue, unfortunately - you would need to contact Microsoft support.

Comment: Here is some more info.  sp_BlitzWho Version = '8.09', VersionDate = '20220408', SQL Server 2019 Standard Edition (RTM-CU16)

Comment: @user2368632 we won't be doing more troubleshooting here in the comments. As I wrote earlier, you would need to contact Microsoft support.